# How do I select and delete a group of Twitter posts / tweets?

Tags: twitter

With Twitter's web UI, it is very hard to see all my Twitter posts / tweets, especially the oldest ones. I have to manually scroll down until the bottom and wait for Twitter to load the next set of tweets. If I want to reach my oldest tweet, this could take forever.

Is there a way to easily select a group of tweets including the oldest ones, and then delete them? I would like to be able to select which of my tweets will be deleted, and not mass delete all of them, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly selective but, **[TweetDelete](http://www.tweetdelete.net/)** has a nifty feature of allowing you to delete tweets older that a specified age. This makes it easier to get rid of the older tweets that might take a long time to scroll through and manually delete with Twitter's web UI.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's API allows you to fetch only the last 3,200 of your tweets. If you want to mass delete *all* your tweets, use [TwitWipe](http://www.twitwipe.com/login.php).

Comment: probably http://www.tweeteraser.com/ - but I haven't checked it out